# Rails Best_in_place activator not working after render partial by remote ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I have a haml table and records are listing with each loop through this instance variable **@academic_classes**, I have placed best_in_place select input to second td object attribute which is **class_category**, here is the code in haml in my partial.

_classes.html.erb

```
- @academic_classs.all.each do |academic_class|
  %tr
    %td= check_box_tag "class_ids[]", academic_class.id
    %td
      - unless academic_class.class_category.blank?
        = best_in_place academic_class, :class_category_id, :as => :select, activator: '#edit-class-category-name_' + academic_class.id.to_s, :collection => ClassCategory.all.map{|m| [m.id, m.name]}, inner_class: "form-control"
        = link_to 'javascript:void(0)', class: "pull-right", id: 'edit-class-category-name_' + academic_class.id.to_s do
          .glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil
      - else
        %em No Category
    %td= academic_class.name
    %td= academic_class.section
    %td= link_to "javascript: void(0)", "data-href" => "#{academic_class_path(academic_class)}", method: :delete, onClick: "confirmDelete(this)" do
      .glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
```

And I am using Bootstrap Tab switching Javascript component but here I am using with remote call and rendering a partial to a div when I click to any one of the tab.

index.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="academic_classes_tab">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <%= link_to "Classes", "#classes_tab", :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'tab', 'data-target' => '#classes', id: "classes_tab"  %>
    </li>

    <li role="presentation">
      <%= link_to "Categories", "#categories_tab", :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => 'tab', 'data-target' => '#categories', class: "categories_tab"  %>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content academic_classes">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="classes">
      <div class="classes">
        <%= render "classes" %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="categories">
      <div class="categories">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now when I click to any one of the tab it uses unobtrusive javascript and render a partial to **.classes** div and **.categories** div as show above

index.js.erb

```
if($("#academic_classes_tab li:first-child").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".classes").html("<%= j render(partial: 'classes') %>")
    $(".categories").html('')
    $(".add_classes").html('')
} else 

if($("#academic_classes_tab li:nth-child(2)").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".categories").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'categories').html_safe %>")
    $(".classes").html('')
    $(".add_classes").html('')
}
```

After when the div loads with ajax my **best_in_place** select activator is not working unless I refresh the page.

Here one thing I noticed that is when I click the label of best in place attribute **class category name** then click again on activator which is the pencil glyph icon with link, as you can see above, the best_in_place is working fine, but I have to do this thing on each label in the list then each of its corresponding activator is working and updating as well.

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong or is there something that needs to be done in this code? Also please tell me any other alternative of this code I want  to use best_in_place select on index page instead of show page, where I can place this to each element. Right now I have placed the object Id to the activator to make it unique.

Comment: Have you tried ending JS statements with `;`, like for `onClick`? Are you using turbolinks (default in Rails 4)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when refreshing a partial and had to use the same workaround of clicking the best in place span in order for my activator to work. This may not be the best solution but mine was to have JavaScript click all of the labels in the same js.erb file I used to render the partial.

```
bips = document.getElementsByClassName('best_in_place');
for (var i = 0; i < bips.length; i++) {
    bips[i].click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js.erb`, rebind your best_in_place fields (you should be able to use the same code you wrote--I'm guessing--in your `application.js` file).

If you are rendering a partial with best_in_place fields in it, then they are rendering just as plain HTML and haven't yet been bound. You can do something like this:

```
$('.best_in_place').best_in_place();
```

and then your bip fields should work again. I'd strongly suggest adding a class to the `%tr` for each `academic_class` (like `%tr.academic`) and then calling best_in_place specifically only on the newly rendered rows (instead of rebinding any other best_in_place elements). After you add the class, you can do:

```
$('.academic .best_in_place').best_in_place();
```